# Cannot find the Cocos2d templates

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, xcode

I am about to upgrade to the last version of Cocos2d and would like to uninstall my current Cocos2d templates before installing the new one but cannot find the templates to delete.

I have looked at a number of web comments on this such as [Uninstall Cocos2D](http://cocos2d-tutorials.com/2012/01/how-to-install-and-uninstall-cocos2d-tutorial/) ans [another uninstall example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287029/how-to-uninstall-cocos2d-templates) but to no avail. However, I still see Cocos2d in my Xcode (4.5) framework. I have been searching my directories but cannot find it.

Is there anyone out there who can give me a hint where to find it so i can delete in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must admit I haven't visited the pages you link to, so I don't know where you have looked already, but on my machine they seem to be in
$HOME/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates